# Tag-it onlyAvalaibleTags option doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tag-it

I use tag-it plugin from https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/downloads. How to  disable adding new tags?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Tags").tagit({
                    singleField: true,
                    singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
                     //  onlyAvailableTags : true,
                     allowNewTags: false,
                    tagSource: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.AvailableTags)]
                });
            });
```

I tried to use `onlyAvailableTags : true` and `allowNewTags: false` options, but there's no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say "but there's no effect", I would guess that `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.AvailableTags)` produces an output that that breaks the javascript syntax. The tags need to be in quotes, otherwise they are treated as variables.

Incorrrect output:

```
tagSource: [my-tag, another-tag]
```

Server-side, I assume you have some kind of `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
ViewBag.AvailableTags = new List<string>
{
    "my-tag",
    "another-tag",
};
```

Then, in your `.cshtml`:

```
tagSource: ["@string.Join("\", \"", ViewBag.AvailableTags)"]
```

This would produce the correct output:

```
tagSource: ["my-tag", "another-tag"]
```

That would be what I'd try first.

Answer (score 1):

I found that by commenting out:

```
 // Autocomplete will create its own tag from a selection and close automatically.
 if (!that.tagInput.data('autocomplete-open')) {
    that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
 }
```

And:

```
// Create a tag when the element loses focus.
// If autocomplete is enabled and suggestion was clicked, don't add it.
if (!that.tagInput.data('autocomplete-open')) {
     that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
}
```

It removes this functionality. Perhaps not the cleanest way of doing it, but it works.

Just comment out the `if(){ }` loops.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for the latest version of tag-it :

```
var tags_list = ['tag1', 'tag2, 'tag3];

$("input[name='subject-tags']").tagit({
    availableTags : tags_list,
    beforeTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
        if(tags_list.indexOf(ui.tagLabel) == -1){
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Tried to make it cleaner by implementing

```
$("input[name='subject-tags']").tagit({
    availableTags : ['tag1', 'tag2, 'tag3],
    beforeTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
        if(this.availableTags.indexOf(ui.tagLabel) == -1){
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

But `this.availableTags` doesn't return the array (return : `undefined`). I'm a JS noob, so something must be wrong with the way I access the property.